# django.db.utils.OperationalError Выдаёт ошибку: no such table: blog_tag

Tags: python, django

Выдаёт ошибку

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: blog_tag

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
        from django.shortcuts import reverse
        from django.utils.text import slugify
        from time import time

    def gen_slug(s):
        new_slug = slugify(s, allow_unicode=True)
        return new_slug + '-' + str(time())


    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
        body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
        date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def  save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.id:
                self.slug = gen_slug(self.title)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    class Tag(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),     # Posts list
        path('post/create/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post_create_url'),     # Post create
        path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),     # Post detail
        path('tags/', tags_list, name='tags_list_url'),     # Tags list
        path('tag/create/', TagCreate.as_view(), name='tag_create_url'),     # Tag create
        path('tag/<str:slug>/', TagDetail.as_view(), name='tag_detail_url')     # Tag detail
    ]
```

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from django.views.generic import View
    from .models import Post, Tag
    from .utils import *
    from .forms import TagForm, PostForm

    # List block
    def posts_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})

    def tags_list(request):
        tags = Tag.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})


    # Detail block
    class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Post
        template = 'blog/post_detail.html'


    class TagDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Tag
        template = 'blog/tag_detail.html'


    # Create block
    class TagCreate(ObjectCreateMixin, View):
        model_form = TagForm
        template = 'blog/tag_create.html'


    class PostCreate(ObjectCreateMixin, View):
        model_form = PostForm
        template = 'blog/post_create_form.html'
```

utils.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from .models import *

    class ObjectDetailMixin:
        model = None
        template = None

        def get(self, request, slug):
                obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
                return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj})


    class ObjectCreateMixin:
        model_form = None
        template = None

        def get(self, request):
            form = self.model_form()
            return render(request, self.template, context={'form': form})

        def post(self, request):
            bound_form = self.model_form(request.POST)
            if bound_form.is_valid():
                new_obj = bound_form.save()
                return redirect(new_obj)
            return render(request, self.template, context={'form': bound_form})
```

forms.py:

```
    from django import forms
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    from .models import Tag, Post

    class TagForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Tag
            fields = ['title', 'slug']
            widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            }


        def clean_slug(self):
            new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()
            if new_slug == 'create':
                raise ValidationError('Slug may not be "Create".')
            if Tag.objects.filter(slug__iexact=new_slug).count():
                raise ValidationError('Slug must be unique. We have "{}" slug already.'.format(new_slug))
            return new_slug


    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'tags']
            widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'tags': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            }

        def clean_slug(self):
            new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()
            if new_slug == 'create':
                raise ValidationError('Slug may not be "Create".')
            return new_slug
```

Comment: Вы миграции применили?

Comment: Да, но это не помогает.

Comment: У Вас миграции нарушены, видимо. Создайте эту таблицу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я просто создал проект заново и скопировал туда код из старого проекта.